# Java textfield validation

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I have to validate a java `text field` which takes only integer values with a maximum length of 10. Entering of other values must be skipped.

I tried this as following. on that case i cant typed full stop.

```
private void jTextField2KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();

        if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)||(c==KeyEvent.VK_STOP ) )){
            getToolkit().beep();

            evt.consume();

            }

    }
```

Comment: And your question is....

Answer (score 3):

Use a JFormattedText field not a JTextField and you can then specify a mask to limit what can be entered (or user a number formatter to have it automatically parsed as a number for you).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: then how can i do it using jFormattedTextField

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: The simple way to create a JFormattedTextField that accepts a number is with `new JFormattedTextField(new NumberFormatter(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance()))`.  To limit the number of characters, you can override the NumberFormatter's getDocumentFilter method, but I suspect what you really want is to place a maximum on the numeric value, in which case a much easier approach is `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0L, 0L, 9_999_999_999L, 1L))`.

Answer (score 3):

For that purposes you can use `DocumentFilter` like next :

```
JTextField f = new JTextField(10);
((AbstractDocument)f.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*");

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass arg0, int arg1, int arg2, String arg3, AttributeSet arg4) throws BadLocationException {
        String text = arg0.getDocument().getText(0, arg0.getDocument().getLength())+arg3;
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if(!matcher.matches()){
            return;
        }
        if(text.length()>10){
            return;
        }
        super.replace(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx.. i'm new to java. can you explain how can i do that?

Comment: code in my answer do what you want. Creates new `JTextField` and set `DocumentFilter`, which has regex for validating digits and validation length.

Comment: how to set DocumentFilter to JTextField?

Comment: what is the method for above code. i'm using netbeans gui. it generate all of the text box

Comment: you need to find creation of your textfield and add my code to that.

Comment: +1, for suggestion DocumentFilter. -1, for variable names and filter implementatation :) There is no need to filter existing text, only text that is about to be added. Your code assumes that all text is appended at the end. It also doesn't take into account you could be replacing selected text so you length calculation is off. Refer to [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a better starting example.